# how to skip day when there is no store opening in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that will skip the days when there is no store opening on that day.

```
Ex:
Day 1 -> Friday
DAy 2 -> Saturday
Day 3 -> Sunday (no store opening)
Day 4 -> Monday
```

Currently my program will skip and add 1 day when there is no store opening.
so it will be like this:

```
Day 3 -> Sunday + 1day = Monday,
```

but my problem is.. the Day 4 which also scheduled on Monday,.

so my actual result will become :

```
Day 3 -> Monday
Day 4 -> Monday (which must be move on Tuesday)
```

What can I do to achieve that?

Here is my code:

````
    var dayOne = td.MinutesFromAttached.Value - 1;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        var possibleDate = context.FirstDay.AddDays(dayOne + i);

        if (!_storeScheduleService.IsStoreOpenForDate(storeId, possibleDate)) continue;

        var scheduleCheck = _storeScheduleService.IsStoreOpen(context.TaskParam.Customer.StoreId.Value, possibleDate);

        var tsDispatch = td.DispatchTime ?? new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0);

        if (tsDispatch < scheduleCheck.Schedule.Open)
        {
            tsDispatch = scheduleCheck.Schedule.Open.Value;
        }
        else if (tsDispatch > scheduleCheck.Schedule.Close)
        {
            tsDispatch = scheduleCheck.Schedule.Close.Value;
        }

        var dateTimeSchedule = new DateTime(possibleDate.Year,
            possibleDate.Month,
            possibleDate.Day,
            tsDispatch.Hours,
            tsDispatch.Minutes,
            tsDispatch.Seconds);

        aTaskExec.ScheduledDispatchedDateTime = dateTimeSchedule;

        break;
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because you are not keeping track of "skipped" days on the next loops iteration. There are multiple ways to solve this problem.

One possibility is to let the `possibleDate` persist outside of the for loop. This will allow you add 1 day to it for each loop iteration.

```
var possibleDate = context.FirstDay.AddDays(dayOne);
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    possibleDate = possibleDate.AddDays(1);
    if (!_storeScheduleService.IsStoreOpenForDate(storeId, possibleDate)) continue;
    ...
}
```

Another option would be to keep track of a skipped day counter

```
int skippedDays = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
   var possibleDate = context.FirstDay.AddDays(dayOne + i + skippedDays);
    possibleDate = possibleDate.AddDays(1);
    if (!_storeScheduleService.IsStoreOpenForDate(storeId, possibleDate))
    {
         skippedDays++;
         continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i've tried that but the result will become like this :

Day 1 -> Friday,
Day 2 -> Saturday,
Day 3 -> Tuesday,
Day 4 -> Monday,